# Node/commander.js - Improper parsing/assignment of parameters

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I have written an utility that can be called via CLI, with arguments and flags.
Unfortunately, for a reason that I ignore, commander.js does not parse the arguments properly. What am I missing?

Here's the commander.js setup script:

```js
import { Command, Option } from "commander";

function parseArguments() {
  const program = new Command();

  program
    .name('video-recorder')
    .description('Video recorder utility capturing screen & sound output')

  program.command("list-devices").description("Lists devices");

  program
    .command("capture")
    .addOption(
      new Option("-p --profile <profile>", "Profile to use to record")
        .default(undefined),
    )
    .addOption(
      new Option(
        "-d --duration <time>",
        "Duration of the video, in format [HH:]mm:ss",
      )
    )
    .argument("<url>", "url to the page of the video")
    .argument("<path>", "path to output to");

  program.parse(process.argv);
  return program;
}

async function main() {
  const program = parseArguments();
  const [url, outpath] = program.args;
    const args = {
      url: url,
      outpath: outpath,
      ... program.opts(),
    };
    console.log(args)
  // ...
}

main();
```

When calling said script using

```bash
node src/main.js capture -p abc -d '9:48' 'https://www.example.com/video-id' '/path/to/output_file.mp4'
```

I get the following args dictionary printed:

```
{ url: 'capture', outpath: '-p' }
```

Which is incorrect. It seems like commander.js skipped the name of the command, and put the arguments first instead of parsing the options provided.

How can I modify my script such that:

1. The subcommand (capture or list-devices) is recognized
2. The options are correctly parsed and the arguments are passed at the end of the cli call line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It is a good idea to trim your example down to as little as possible to demonstrate the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a subcommand like `capture`, add an action handler to the subcommand using `.action()`.

The action handler is passed the parsed arguments and options.